# Any photon colliders in the past?

Tags: experimental-physics, history, experimental-technology

People have been thinking about a photon-photon collider (see [this](http://www.symmetrymagazine.org/breaking/2008/11/05/should-a-photon-photon-collider-precede-the-ilc) and [this](http://www.lnf.infn.it/conference/lc08/talk/deroeck.pdf)) as an add-on or to supplement the [ILC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Linear_Collider), the next generation linear collider.

My question is, have there been any photon-photon colliders running in the past*, including those running below the $e^+ e^-$ threshold to study non-linear effects in photon scattering?

*Virtual/Weissäcker-Williams/Equivalent photon-photon colliders don't count.

Comment: It might just be me who is not a lets say a proffessor, but aren't photons massless, and therefore do not interact with each other? What would be the point of such a colider?

Comment: Photons interact with each other through higher order effects, where the photons will pair produce $e^+e^-$ pairs, and then those annihilate into new photons.

Comment: Related but not a duplicate: [Inverse pair production w/hohlaraum as photon target - is this experiment going to be carried out?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/330914/83380)

Answer (score 1):

It was done at SLAC in 1996. See [Positron Production
in Multiphoton Light-by-Light Scattering](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/cgi-wrap/getdoc/slac-pub-7564.pdf). The paper was in [Physics Review Letters](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.79.1626).

For some background reading, there’s plenty of arXiv papers with [photon-photon interaction](http://arxiv.org/find/grp_physics/1/ti:+AND+EXACT+photon_photon+interaction/0/1/0/all/0/1) in the title. Also see [Kirk McDonald's website](http://physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/) for a wealth of information. He's a SLAC guy. For example, check out the 1998 PhysicsToday article [gamma rays create matter just by plowing into laser light](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/e144/pt_51(2)_17_98.pdf).

The photon-photon collisions weren't as "pure" as what the Imperial physicists are trying to do, but it was still gamma-gamma pair production.