# If light is made up of electromagnetic waves, then if I put a magnetic close to a laser beam, shouldn't the light bend?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electricity

Light always moves in a straight line unless gravity acts on it strongly, but since it is made of electric and magnetic waves, shouldn't it be pulled towards different charges and magnetic, or is light neutral?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can visible light be affected by magnetism?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/450208/can-visible-light-be-affected-by-magnetism) See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67464/can-a-light-be-bent-by-a-magnetic-field).

Comment: "Light always moves in a straight line unless gravity acts on it strongly..." This premise is not true. The direction of a beam of light can be changed, say, by using a mirror to reflect the light. The reflection occurs because the light interacts (electromagnetically) with the mirror. As another example, light beams can change direction due to refraction in a prism or other semi-transparent material (again an electromagnetic effect).